# почему не отправляется форма?

Tags: javascript, html

чтобы отключить повторную отправка формы, написал простую валидацию и если форма ее проходит тогда блокирую кнопку, но форма перестала отправляться. Как будто кнопко submit перестала работать как submit, то есть она не смотрит теперь на атрибут required.

```
    $(document).on('click','.best-price-popup__footer-close', validate);


    function validate(){
        let email = document.getElementById("bpp_email");
        let phone = document.getElementById("bpp_phone");
        let link = document.getElementById("bpp_link");
        let price = document.getElementById("bpp_price");
        let checkbox = document.getElementById("bpp_checkbox");

        let emailTest = /^[\w-\.]+@[\w-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i;

        if(email.value.length < 3 || emailTest.test(email.value) == false) {
            return false
        }

        if(phone.value.length < 1 ) {
            return false
        }

        if(link.value.length < 5 ) {
            return false
        }

        if(!price.value) {
            return false
        }

        if(!checkbox.checked) {
            return false
        }

        let submit = document.querySelector('.best-price-popup__footer-close')
        if(submit != null) {
            submit.disabled = true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Кучу if сократить бы до одного... И добавьте html - `best-price-popup__footer-close` что это?

Comment: @InDevX это кнопка submit в форме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы кнопку заблокировали до отправки, перед submit.disabled вызовите form.submit()

Comment: Спасибо помогло